# Cannot install tensorflow on fresh ubuntu partition: tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, python-wheel

I installed pip3 and upgraded it. When trying to install tensorflow, I get the following:

```
daniel@popeax:~$ sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/695981/platform-not-supported-for-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-14-04-2

Answer (score 0):

This question is identical to the one I had answered on Ask Ubuntu at https://askubuntu.com/q/778698/15003:

For now, according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2188#issuecomment-216186066, the solution is to download and rename the wheel and install using the renamed wheel:

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
mv tensorflow-0.8.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl tensorflow-0.8.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow-0.8.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

If you are willing to wait a bit, the wheel for Python 3.5 should be out soon according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2188#issuecomment-220363241.